# How to set fix size of jlabel?

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, null-layout-manager

I am trying to make a java desktop application where I am using multiple `JLabel` I want to set fix height and width of `JLabel`. How can I achieve this?

Here is my code

```
public class Second extends JFrame
{
    JPanel panel1,panel2;
    JLabel label=new JLabel();
    ArrayList<JLabel> lbllist = new ArrayList<>();

    public Second()  
    {
        super("Simple Timer");
        {
            getContentPane().setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255,255,255));
        } 
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        Container c = getContentPane();
        c.setLayout( new FlowLayout());
        setUndecorated(true);
        Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        setBounds(0,0,screenSize.width, screenSize.height);

        panel2=new JPanel();
        panel2.setBounds(360, 180, 360, 1020);
        panel2.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255,153,51));
        c.add(panel2);
        JPanel panel3 = createPanel();
        panel1.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        panel1.add(panel3);

        JPanel panel4 = createPanel(); 
        panel2.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    //  jPanel2.setLayout(null);
        panel2.add(panel4);

        setLayout(null);
   }

   private JPanel createPanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1, 10, 5));
        EmptyBorder panelBorder = new EmptyBorder(10, 5, 10, 10);
        panel.setBorder(panelBorder);
        panel.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 153, 51));
        panel.setOpaque(true);
        EmptyBorder border1 = new EmptyBorder(5, 20, 15, 18);

        Border border = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLUE, 2);
        for (int i = 0; i <11; i++) {
            label = new JLabel("<html>Case &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Item&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; CaseNum<br><font color=yellow>Party1<br>Party2</font></html>");
            label.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Times New Roman", 1, 18));
            label.setBorder(border);
            label.setSize(300, 100);
            label.setBorder(border1);
            Dimension d = label.getPreferredSize();
            label.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
            label.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255,255 ));
            label.setOpaque(true);
            lbllist.add(label);
            panel.add(label);
        }
        return panel;
    }
```

When I reduce text size or text from `JLabel`  then size of `JLabel` reduced but I want that when i reduced  or remove any text from `JLabel` but size of Jlabel should not reduced it should fix

How can I get this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: See [Should I avoid the use of set(Preferred|Maximum|Minimum)Size methods in Java Swing?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7229226/418556)  (Yes.)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can set a fixed the size by setting the minimum, preferred and maximum size:

```
setMinimumSize(width, height);
setPreferredSize(width, height);
setMaximumSize(width, height);
```

As the [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7229226/should-i-avoid-the-use-of-setpreferredmaximumminimumsize-methods-in-java-swi) from **MadProgrammer**, you need to override these methods, not using them from outside, based on the reasons mentioned in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7229226/should-i-avoid-the-use-of-setpreferredmaximumminimumsize-methods-in-java-swi).

Comment: i will have to use all three or any one

Comment: You can use `setMaximumSize`, but i want to show you what the `API` offer.

Comment: To be clear, you want fixed size for the width of JLabel or its text contents?

Comment: i want to fix size of j label and it should not reduced   when i remove text or content form jlabel

Comment: Then try to use the method above all.

Comment: i used  but when im remove any content from jlabel then  sized of jlabel reduced

Comment: You may wish to consider taking a look at [Should I avoid the use of set(Preferred|Maximum|Minimum)Size methods in Java Swing?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7229226/should-i-avoid-the-use-of-setpreferredmaximumminimumsize-methods-in-java-swi)

Comment: setPreferedSize must be setPreferredSize and (width, height) must be (new Dimension(width, height))

Answer (score 5):

if this method not work

```
setMinimumSize(width, height);
setPreferredSize(width, height);
setMaximumSize(width, height);
```

then use it

```
setMinimumSize(new Dimension(width, height));
setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height));
setMaximumSize(new Dimension(width, height));
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `JLabel.setPreferredSize(width, height);`
The jpanel does not have a layout, try Jpanel pane =new JPanel(new FlowLayout（））；

Answer (score 2):

An easy work around (without overriding existing classes) is to;

- Create a JPanel specifically for the component
- Set the size for the JPanel
- Place the component within the JPanel
- Place the JPanel where you would have originally placed the component

e.g.

```
JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel(); //Assume this is the panel you are placing things into.

JLabel nameLabel = new JLabel("Name:");
JPanel nameLabelPanel = new JPanel();
nameLabelPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 25));
JPanel.add(nameLabel);
mainPanel.add(nameLabelPanel);
```